# Saving request data in CakePHP between two actions in controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

I have two actions which are like pages in my controller. I two buttons: `next` and `previous` too. How can I save my `$this->request->data` between two action in the same controller ? When i'm pressing `previous`, i need to have all the data on the previous page, which the user entered not to disappear.

Comment: Can't You just use `$this->Session->write()` to set data in one action, and `$this->Session->read()` to get data in another action?

Comment: @BogdanKuštan, but i have many actions, so i have to write read and write stuff in all these actions ?

Comment: Please, clarify what are you trying to achieve? something like multistep registration form?

Comment: @BogdanKuštan, its just a form, which hast 3 parts. every part(excepting the first) has two buttons: next and previous. I'm trying to achieve saving request data between this parts. So when I forgot to fill something in the previous  part, i just click the button previous and go to the precious part where all data remain as set before.

Comment: You would be better off using javascript to achieve that. That way request logic is easily handled.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have lots of fields and fields are named uniquely, you could add correspondig values to session when handling form in controller.

```
$this->Session->write('Form1.field1', $value);
```

After that, you could fetch saved values from session every time you visit that form page again and use them as default values in form.

```
$this->set('Form1.field1', $this->Session->read('Form1.field1'));
```

I must admit, that this is not very handy way doing it, and by my self, I would definetly go with JavaScript instead.